# Encoding scheme for SSJS library when exported via DXL

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

This is an extension of my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891295/import-ssjs-script-library-using-dxl-in-a-database). When we export a SSJS library to DXL we get output which contains this:

```
<item name="$ServerJavaScriptLibrary" sign="true">
<rawitemdata type="1">
....ENCODED SSJS....
</rawitemdata>
</item>
```

I previously thought that the encoding scheme used here is Base64. But after trying unsuccessfuly to import SSJS library I think it is not. While searching I found that the `type="1"` refers to `TYPE_COMPOSITE` while `type="14`" refers to Base64 (please correct me if I am wrong on this one). I tried to use `type="14"` in my XML fil, put Base64 encoded code in `rawitemdata` tag and then tried to import the file. It created SSJS library in the database but its content was blank.

I found [this link](http://hermes.intec.co.uk/Intec/Blog.nsf/dx/Import%20agent.txt/$file/Import%20agent.txt) where it is importing a Theme by encoding it in Base64 but it prepends the encoded string by "YQAYAAAAAAA6AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYABMAAAAOgA6AAAAAAAAAAAA". I tried to prepend it in my encoded SSJS code and then import it but still unsuccessful.

Which encoding scheme should be used so that I can import the SSJS code in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SSJS library is stored in richtext records. The encoded string before the data of the SSJS library is the base64 encoded header information these records.

Here you can find a working example how to encapsulate and import a SSJS library with DXL into a Database: 
[Quick-n-Dirty: Import SSJS libraries with DXL](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1080)

Comment: Thanks a ton Sven! Your code worked. I tried it on my local machine and for that purpose I had to replace the usage of `sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess` with `session`. But when I open the imported file at the end of it I see 4 extra characters - one special character (a black filled square), space and characters of 's' and 'd'. Any ideas why? Is it because I am running this on local machine? I could not comment this on your blog as it keeps showing me the message `FEHLER: Unreadable CAPTCHA token file` despite entering the correct word for captcha.

Comment: @Naveen: Thanks for the feedback. The last WP update killed the captcha plugin, it works now again. To your question: Hmm, currently I can not explain the "extra" characters at the end, because this is the code of your SSJS library. Is this a general problem for *every* library, or just a specific one?

Comment: After a bit of trial-and-error I found an interesting observation. If I try to import function written like `test1 = function() {}`. Then there is no problem with imported script library. But if I try to import a function like `function test1() {}`. Then the imported scripted library has a special character at the end. I don't know why! The error in Problems view shows this message `Lexical error at line 17, column 2.  Encountered: "\u25a0" (9632), after : ""`. Any ideas why? Also I was still unable to comment your blog as it showed me message `Spam deleted` every time I tried to submit.

Comment: @Naveen: The last bytes in the DXL encoded part are the ascii encoded chars from your SSJS code. I think this has something to do with the data send from the browser. Can you check if your code can be imported if hardcoded in the java class? P.S. I checked the Anti-Spam-Plugin in my blog, it should work now...

Answer (score 0):

The prepended string is a checksum; when exporting a library to DXL, the Base64 includes a prefix that allows the importer to validate the content. This checksum approach is also used when exporting XPage and Custom Control design elements to DXL. Hence, if you import this DXL exactly as it was exported, the import will be successful. If, however, you modify the encoded content and prepend it with the same prefix, the import will fail because the checksum will no longer match.

I have requested information from IBM on what algorithm is used to generate this checksum to allow importing of externally generated design elements, but have never received a response.

Comment: Finally, a reply... :)    In this [link](http://hermes.intec.co.uk/Intec/Blog.nsf/dx/Import%20agent.txt/$file/Import%20agent.txt) the code imports theme and encodes in Base64. It then puts it in `<rawitemdata Type='1'>` tag with some modifications. If you get any ideas from this, then do tell me.